# Problem with encoding Readlines(), special character

Tags: r, encoding, readlines

I have some accents in my file and I'm trying to open this file with the proper encoding, but every time I'm opening this file, my accents come up with special characters (), although I mentioned to open the file with encoding = UTF-8

```
mes_keywords_to_check <- readLines("mot cle holidays.txt", encoding='UTF-8')
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue:

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")

write("Ole Gunnar Solskjær", temp)

readLines(temp, encoding = "UTF-8")

[1] "Ole Gunnar Solskj\xe6r"
```

However, in my case it is resolved by omitting the encoding parameter in `readLines` (or using `latin1` instead of `UTF-8`):

```
readLines(temp)
[1] "Ole Gunnar Solskjær"

readLines(temp, encoding = "latin1")
[1] "Ole Gunnar Solskjær"
```

Comment: thank you. It is working, but I don't understand it is not working with UT8?

Comment: I don't know enough about unicode. "`UTF-16`" also works, for what it's worth.